How does Principal Asano get everyone to hate class 3E so much?
In S2 E11 of Assassination Classroom, you can see the aftermath of Principal Asano turning the student body against class 3E.
The students become very hateful, and there are metaphorical giant centipedes crawling around and resting on the students. When the centipedes go away, the students become very drained.
How does Principal Asano get the students to hate class 3E so much?
